# How to access virtual camera's Aim Horizontal and Vertical Speed parameters through script?

Tags: unity, cinemachine

I have a script that accesses the same thing but in freelook camera, but it doesn't work the same way with virtual camera apparently.

```
using Cinemachine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject inventory;
    public GameObject Button;
    public CinemachineFreeLook camera_ThirdPerson;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera camera_FirstPerson;
   
    private bool isInventoryVisible;
    private bool isButtonVisible;

    void Start()
    { 
        camera_ThirdPerson = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CinemachineFreeLook>();
        camera_FirstPerson = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
        isButtonVisible = true;
        isInventoryVisible = false;
        inventory.SetActive(isInventoryVisible);
        Button.SetActive(isButtonVisible);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            isInventoryVisible = !isInventoryVisible;
            inventory.SetActive(isInventoryVisible);
            UpdateCursorState();
            UpdateCameraState();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
        {
            isButtonVisible = !isButtonVisible;
            Button.SetActive(isButtonVisible);
            UpdateCursorState();
            UpdateCameraState();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateCursorState()
    {
        if (isInventoryVisible || isButtonVisible)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCameraState()
    {
        if (isInventoryVisible || isButtonVisible)
        {
            camera_ThirdPerson.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0f;
            camera_ThirdPerson.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            camera_ThirdPerson.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 450f;
            camera_ThirdPerson.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 4f;
        }
    }
}
```

The `.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed` doesn't work with the virtual camera nor does `m_HorizontalAxis.m_MaxSpeed` nor `m_Horizontal.m_MaxSpeed`.  I'm just trying to do the same thing I did with the freelook camera to the virtual camera.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var pov = vcam.GetCinemachineComponent<CinemachinePOV>()
pov.m_HorizontalAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
pov.m_VerticalAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
```

Unless you select the aim type POV, you cannot access any data related to speed because it does not exist.